# How to change angular 2 google map marker label color?

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps, angular2-google-maps

[image]hello I am using Angular2 Google Maps and i want change my maker label color

code :

```
<agm-map [zoom]="7" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [styles]='[
            {
                elementType : "labels.text",
                stylers : [{
                   color:"#ffffff"
                }]
            }]'> <agm-marker>....</agm-marke>
```

please help me ...

Comment: Have you tried any of the other allowed values of elementType, such as `'labels.icon'|
      'labels.text'|'labels.text.fill'|'labels.text.stroke'`?

Comment: @Adam yes but its change google default label colorbut i eant change my dynamic table text color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved by change css :

```
.gm-style div{color: #fff !important; font-weight: bold;}
```